# Actual and formal parameters

Tags: java

I am writing code in Java which has multiple methods and these methods have multiple variables. I want the other methods to access the variables of another method using actual and formal parameters. How can I do it?

I am pasting an example of the problem I'm facing.

```
Error : variable is not defined.
```

**Code**

```
  public class example {

    public void addition() {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 10;
        int c = a + b;
    }

    public void result() {
        System.out.println("The result for the above addition is" + c);
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll need to learn that javascript is not java (your code is java, your tag is javascript) - but, since `c` is declared inside `addition` it's not accessible inside `result`

Comment: can you help me mate?

Comment: yes but I need to use actual and formal parameters to pass the value.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you're even saying - you have no parameters (neither formal nor actual - whatever that means) at all, so perhaps wait for a `java` kid to come and help

Comment: @roydenrahul  May be it's clear to you. Please state your question in clear and concise way.

Comment: any update for this question ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

well, your java syntax is quite wrong... if you need to do an addition, you can do as follows:

```
public class Addition {

    public static int addition(int a, int b)
    {
     int c= a + b;
     return c;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1; 
        int b = 10;
        int c = addition(a,b);
        System.out.println("The result for the above addition is " + c);
    }

}
```

where addition function does add a + b and return the result to your main method.

Answer (score 1):

> IM GETTING AN ERROR SAYING VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED

You should declare `c` as global variable

```
public class Example {

    int c;

    public void addition() {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 10;
        c = a + b;
    }

    public void result() {
        System.out.println("The result for the above addition is " + c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.addition();
        e.result();
    }
}
```